# How can I skip files in a tar on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: git, tar

What I'd like to do is archive my git master branch and pipe that to tar, but exclude a few file types and directories. This tar file will then be untarred to my web directory.

Comment: git archive -o xyz.tar ?

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the list of paths to archive

```
 git archive -o /tmp/archive.tar -- html/ images/ css/ index.htm
```

Or you can reuse git-ls-files

```
 git ls-files -z | xargs -z git archive -o /tmp/archive.tar --
```

git-ls-files has options to exclude files (optionally using customg exclude files analogous to the per-directoty .gitignore files). `man git-ls-files`

Answer (score 0):

Just run the git archive and then script the removal of the file afterward with regular tar manipulation.